# How do I use a relaycommand on startup and how do I do it if the method I want to pass is within another class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am interested in learning more about MVVM. I have taken a look at the MVVM Demo App. I understand many of the major concepts behind it.

When I began playing with the app, I wanted to open one of the tabviews by default upon the app starting up. However I am unsure on how to do that.

In the app, I think I understand that when a control panel button is clicked (e.g. View All Customers), the commandrelay creates a new AllCustomersViewModel and the data template applies the view to the viewmodel, the new workspace is created to the Workspaces collection and the tab opens because of the databinding in the main window.

I have no idea how to start this process other than clicking the hyperlink. I know that I need to call `new RelayCommand(param => this.ShowAllCustomers())` but I don't understand how to call this without any user interaction, or how to call it from outside of the mainwindowviewmodel, e.g. from the app's onstartup method.

Can someone please advise on the best way to use a relaycommand on the start up of an app? Also, how do I use a relaycommand if the method I want to pass is within another class?

---

VMaleev has correctly given me a method to call the command, however the example provided was specific to a the collection of commands. What if I have a method `Public ICommand HelpPageCommand` which creates a new command based on a `ShowHelpPage` method where ShowHelpPage is;

```
HelpViewModel workspace = new HelpViewModel();
this.Workspaces.Add(workspace);
this.SetActiveWorkspace(workspace);
```

How would I call this command then?
- Simple, if the method is ICommand, then simply method.execute(null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you are talking about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article.

To call RelayCommand without user interaction, you just should write:

1. If want to call from MainWindowViewModel (for example, in constructor):

   ```
   _commands.FirstOrDefault(q => q.DisplayName == Strings.MainWindowViewModel_Command_ViewAllCustomers).Command.Execute(null);
   ```
2. If want to call from App.xaml.cs (on application startup, code is taken from example and only one line added) or something else place where you have access to view model instance:

   ```
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnStartup(e);

       MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

       // Create the ViewModel to which 
       // the main window binds.
       string path = "Data/customers.xml";
       var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(path);

       // When the ViewModel asks to be closed, 
       // close the window.
       EventHandler handler = null;
       handler = delegate
       {
           viewModel.RequestClose -= handler;
           window.Close();
       };
       viewModel.RequestClose += handler;

       // Allow all controls in the window to 
       // bind to the ViewModel by setting the 
       // DataContext, which propagates down 
       // the element tree.
       window.DataContext = viewModel;

       // the following line is added
       viewModel.Commands.FirstOrDefault(q => q.DisplayName == Strings.MainWindowViewModel_Command_ViewAllCustomers).Command.Execute(null);

       window.Show();
   }
   ```

If the method you want to pass is in another class, there are two ways to do it:

- pub/sub mechanism (by using c# events)
- have access from every instance of view model to all instances of your view models. In this case you are able to pass method of any instance of view model as parameter of RelayCommand

Hope, it helps